# Prioritizing Android service for playing background music

Tags: android, service, streaming, media-player, kill

I have a an Android service that streams background music and occasionally the hosting process seems to die playing the music while under certain loads like opening a dozen or tabs of heavy sites in Chrome on my Galaxy S3 (4.1.1). From the research I've done I know this is a topic covered in many forums but I'm hoping to get some advice here for any other techniques.

For want of a better expression, I'd like to know if there's a way to decrease the chance of Android killing off my service after it deems it's not as important as other processes.

Things I've implemented so far:

1. UI-level activity/fragment is bound to the service along with sending play/pause etc. commands via onStart() (the issue happens when the app itself is NOT in the foreground/not visible to the user - except the notification).
2. Service implements startForeground()/stopForeground()
3. Service also implements AudioFocus.

Approach I read about and considered:
Using something like IntentService/HandlerThread to run the MediaPlayer on its own worker thread and setting the thread's priority higher, but as Android's process prioritizing features don't take into account my app's internal thread management I don't foresee this improving the situation (please correct me if this statement is wrong).

Browsing a bunch of websites while playing music in the background I don't think is a huge task, especially on a high spec device like an S3, and the user I think would rather have their music keep playing in the background even if it means switching tabs in Chrome means it has to refresh some pages sometimes.

If anybody has some tips or advice thanks in advance.

Comment: You're already using the AudioManager focus API, right? If you're also using startForeground() then I think you've done all you can. You can't really cater for the user caning their device while your app is running in the background.

Comment: Oh yes I forgot to mention I'm also using that. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Use remote service to play the music. It uses much less memory while running in the background and so there's less chance of it getting killed. My music player that is currently under development manages to keep playing even on a 512MB RAM phone while playing Modern Combat 4.